# Random Spacing in generated PDF

Tags: chapters, vspace

I am writing my thesis in Latex.

And I noticed that there are random white spaces and blank pages being added before certain chapters while the code is identical throughout. Let me know what more information is required, to resolve this issue.

As it is my first post here.

Comment: Chapters usually start at a new page. If the page before is not full, there will be white space at the bottom of the page. Also, chapters often starts at an odd-numbered page (two-side layout). Thus, it can happen, that the page before (even-numbered) remains empty.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Wow, that explains the not so random white page now. But there is also some vertical empty space on the page this chapter starts, compared to other chapters this particular chapter name is shown on 2nd quarter of the page.

Comment: latex never adds white space randomly, any space is a result of instructions in your document. You need to show the code you have used and say which spaces in the output you need to change.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the code for my complete document is over thousand lines long, there is no immediate code before it, should I post the whole document and code somewhere?

Comment: The space at the top of the page, where a chapter starts, is by design. The method to reduce the space depends on the document class and some packages used.

Comment: you should be able to make a two or three page example starting from a copy of your document and deleting everything not relevant to the question, and add it to your question here. Otherwise it is pretty hard to guess what to suggest.

Comment: Suggestions for a good minimal working example are: keep the prelude of your document (i.e. the `\usepackage` things), use package `lipsum` freely to replace the irrelevant text, make sure to replicate the issue, put everything in one file and send it to us. It would be best to remove nonsense things from the prelude, but while doing so you might even solve the issue yourself, and it takes time.

Comment: but has heiko already answered your question, ie if you are using the equivalent of `\documentclass[twoside,openright]{book}` blank pages will be issued as needed to make chapters start on an odd page.  Is there still more to answer?

Comment: Thanks all, Appreciate the comments since I know the reason for empty pages, In creating a smaller document. I removed everything inside the chapters and it looks normal now. So something in the content of chapters is causing it. Will try to debug it myself :) thanks

Comment: It is being caused by two figures posted immediately to one another. I will solve it and then post it in comments here.